# Dockerizing Next.js 13 that has dynamic server functions

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js, deployment, react-server-components

So I'm trying to dockerize Next.js 13 app router with Nginx for production deployment. To do so, I use static export in my Next.js app. However, as written in the docs (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports#unsupported-features),  I can't use dynamic server functions such as rewrites, middleware, etc. For the `rewrites` there's a solution already which is by using Nginx rewrite function. However, I need to use other functions such as middleware and headers.
Example case on using `headers` is when trying to fetch data on server component:

```js
const getPosts = async (query: { take: number; lastCursor?: string }): Promise<IGetPostsResponse> => {
  const host = headers().get('host');
  const url = new URL(`http://${host}/api/public/posts`);
  url.searchParams.append('take', query.take.toString());
  if (query.lastCursor) {
    url.searchParams.append('lastCursor', query.lastCursor);
  }
  const res = await fetch(url);

  if (res.status === 404) return notFound();
  if (!res.ok) throw new Error('Something went wrong!');

  return res.json();
};
```

above `getPosts` function called in server component and it needs full url to successfully call the api. That's why I use `headers` to get the host/base url since the base url can be different in dev and prod.

've been browsing around and still not yet find any example on static export deployment Next.js 13 app dir with these server functions.

**Is there any solution or alternatives on handling this server functions in deploying containerized/dockerized Next.js 13 app? or maybe there's a best practice to deploy Next.js 13 app with Nginx using Docker?**

Been struggling on deploying dockerized Next.js app with Nginx ...

Comment: Did you follow the official tutorial for dockerizing your next.js app? https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying#docker-image

Comment: @Geilmaker yes i read the official next.js docs about static export, it said ``headers`` function cannot be used but there isn't alternative of it

Comment: Why you want static export instead of the docker export explained in the docs, when you want to use docker? Also you should really think about your approach reading the host from the http header. Even tho browsers will ofc send the normal http requests and that will be the most, still its possible to send malicious request with a faked host header and try to compromise your system. Might be a security risk. I think a better way to handle this would be the use of environment variables.